# how do I get Grunt to include bootstrap-theme.css in the build?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using the default `gruntfile.js` that's scaffolded out by Yeoman.  It *looks* like it should include the `bootstrap-theme.css` file that's in the `bower_components` directory, but the resulting page isn't showing those styles.  What am I missing?

**Update:**
I don't know if it's the *right* way to do it, but I found that if I add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />` to the `build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css` block, the file is found and included.  I haven't tested the grunt build, only serve (but I assume it works).

Comment: What yeoman generator are you using?

Comment: the standard `angular` generator

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because the css file has dash `-`.

in the `Gruntfile.js` you can se the regex that find all css files:

```
files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
```

In my case I don't modify this line, just rename/remove the dash and works fine.